# How to collect a stateflow from a Custom View?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-stateflow

[This article](https://www.sasikanth.dev/using-viewmodels-in-custom-views/) explains how to use ViewModels in custom views :

```
class SummaryView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {

  private val viewModel by lazy {
      ViewModelProvider(findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner()!!).get<SummaryViewModel>()
  }

  override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
      super.onAttachedToWindow()

      viewModel.summaryModel.observe(findViewTreeLifecycleOwner()!!, ::populateSummaryView)
  }

}
```

It works well, but how can I use this technique using StateFlow instead of LiveData?
How can I do this without having a reference to the fragment?

```
class SummaryView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {

  private val viewModel by lazy {
      ViewModelProvider(findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner()!!).get<SummaryViewModel>()
  }

  override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
      super.onAttachedToWindow()

      lifecycleScope.launch {
          viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
              viewModel.summaryModel.collect {

              }
          }
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried this way? `findViewTreeLifecycleOwner()?.lifecycleScope?.launch {/* ... */}`